# Meta tag not updating when deploy in angular universal

Tags: angular, seo, metadata, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I use angular version 15 and I want to update meta tag after API call and I check meta tag in localhost when use `npm run dev:ssr` or `npm run serve:ssr` it work and updated in view page source but when I deploy in view page source not update meta tag.

In my localhost

[image: in localhost]

After deploy

[image: in alpha]

sample code for update meta tag from API is below

```
getArticles(body:any){
return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.articleService.articleDetail(body).then(data => {
        let response: any = data;
        this.meta.updateTag({name: 'keywords', content: response.result.publicationName || 'keyword in article'});
        resolve(response.result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/'])
        resolve(undefined)
    })
})}
```

Comment: Do you have NodeJS installed on the server? What backend stack are you using?

Comment: backend I use Express